# Spring security url interception with different roles

Tags: spring-security

Our Application is implemented with spring security and I am using the following syntax for url based role access.

For example, the below one entry allows url having "schoolspecificassessment" with the role admin.

```
security:intercept-url pattern="/schoolspecificassessment" access="hasAnyRole('admin')" />
```

Problem here is,
if I log out from admin and logged in as a normal user I should not be able to access the url containing "schoolspecificassessment". But even the normal users are able to access.

If i do restart of Jboss server it is giving unauthorized message for normal users.

I am doing the following things on logout.

```
session.clear();
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null); 
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

But still some session is cached at the server level I feel. I am not sure how to solve this issue.
I am using Jboss server AS 7.1

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks,
Sivaranjani D

Comment: Why do you do logout by yourself? Anyway try with `session.invalidate();`.

Comment: My session is of SessionAware object. So i can't do session.invalidate since it is a map.

But, i tried the spring logout also as below.
   <security:logout logout-url="/Logout" logout-success-url="/e-elarning.jsp"/>

But still I am having the same problem.

Comment: Get hold of real session object not a map and invalidate it.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support.
I tried session.invalidate() also. Still some where the caching is happening some where. After server restart it works perfectly.
Is there anything like session persistent on jboss?

Comment: As always, enable debug logging and check the log. Spring Security logs detailed information on how each request is handled and if there is an authenticated session and user it will be obvious. If you don't see this then you need to look elsewhere - is the request actually being handled by Spring Security at all? Is your browser caching the page? Be more detailed in writing your questions. For example, don't say a 'url containing "schoolspecificassessment"', give the exact request URL. Perhaps you should try "/schoolspecificassessment*" if it isn't an exact match?

Comment: I solved the issue.
The problem was with the "authoritiesByUsernameQuery".
I was using two question marks in my query. But usually spring's internal implementation fills only one question mark with the username.
So it was failing in executing the query.